# Eval Formatting using ASP.Net Markup (only)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a repeater. One of the items in the repeater is a label. This label should display the TaxRate value. I am able to do this using the following markup.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTaxRate" runat="server" Text = '  <%# Eval("TaxRate")  %>'></asp:Label>
```

Now, I need to add a `$` sign just before the tax rate value. How can we do it using ASP.Net markup only?

Note: Solution using javascritpt is not anticipated.

Note: I cannot replace label with any other control or get rid of the label

Comment: Well doesn't `<%# "$" + Eval("TaxRate")  %>` work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nunespascal answer.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTaxRate" runat="server" Text = '<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Eval("TaxRate"))) == true ? "" : Eval("TaxRate", "${0}")%>  ' > </asp:Label>
```

**IMPROVEMENT**

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Amount") ) %>
```

or

```
<%# ((double)Eval("Amount")).ToString("C") %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TaxRate", "{0:c}") %>
```

(from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck.aspx))

Comment: :) anyway, the usage of `.Eval` with a format is really nice!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTaxRate" runat="server" Text = '  <%# Eval("TaxRate", "${0}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, and takes into account cultural differences in currency

```
'<%# Eval("TaxRate","{0:C2}") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, working on some legacy code, I have a similar issue.
The overload for the format on Eval, can be also used for any custom string.

On my scenario:

```
//Displayed regardless there is a value to evaluate or not.
<%#Eval("ContractLength") + " Years" %>

//Displayed only when there is a value to evaluate.
<%#Eval("ContractLength","{0} Years") %>
```

On your scenario:

```
//Displayed regardless there is a value to evaluate or not.
<%#"$" + Eval("TaxRate") %>

//Displayed only when there is a value to evaluate.
<%#Eval("TaxRate","${0}") %>
```